# magento connection not fully secure

Tags: security, magento, ssl

I am having an problem securing my site.I went to System - configuration - web and i changed edited the secure  configuration

[![secure][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVD4k.png to match the image and my site became secure. the only problem is, everywhere on my site i have a secure connection in the backend and frontend execpt for the home page.It says your connection is not fully secure.  https://truckpartsactions.com/

Comment: in https://truckpartsactions.com/skin/frontend/humvee/default/css/camera.css

Comment: you are calling: http://111.93.221.219/ECO/mag/humvee/skin/frontend/humvee/default/images/gears.svg

Comment: i do not understand your comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: you are right and i have moved this question